# how do I merge two DFs pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a DF:

| IDs |
| --- |
| TIRL002 |
| GRUP003 |
| BUMB004 |
| TIRL002 |
| GRUP003 |
| BUMB004 |

I have another DF:

| Names | IDs |
| --- | --- |
| Tirone Lang | TIRL002 |
| GroupDB | GRUP003 |
| BumbEver | BUMB004 |
| GroupDB | GRUP003 |
| BumbEver | BUMB004 |
| Tirone Lang | TIRL002 |

That's what I want to do (kind of VLOOKUP function):

| IDs | Names |
| --- | --- |
| TIRL002 | Tirone Lang |
| GRUP003 | GroupDB |
| BUMB004 | BumbEver |
| TIRL002 | Tirone Lang |
| GRUP003 | GroupDB |
| BUMB004 | BumbEver |

I have a lot of these IDs and names (about 300) and I tried to `pd.merge` them and it works, but it changes the order of the values to alphabetical. How can I ignore this and stick to the correct order in my final DF?

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('2.csv')
   
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on ='IDs', how ='inner')
print(result)
```

Comment: add `sort=False` as parameter?

Comment: @mozway I tried, it's not working